# Foreign Key Problems with Hibernate (Bug?)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, firebird

at our current project we are experiencing some difficulties. I recently changed some Hibernate Beans (our Article Bean and some underlying stuff) and I ran some tests and everything looked fine. Now my teammate is having exceptions with this message:

`Foreign key (FK_09fd525ae6654c059394d22cc15:ARTBILDER [artikel_fk,servdat_fk])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ARTIKEL [AUTOIN_FIX])`

The annotations are definitely correct. I had the same problem and decided to setup the project on my computer from scratch and the problems were gone. What can be the reason for these problems?

We are working on a legacy database and are only mapping our objects to the database and not generating the database with hibernate. And we are using HibernateSearch for full-text search (maybe this is related, because the first time this occured was after I added the HibernateSearch Annotations).

We are using a Firebird 2.5 instance.

EDIT:

here is the property the error is coming from:

The ID Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ID implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1810044174631580834L;

    private Long autoin;
    private Integer serverId;

    public ID() {
    }

    public ID(Long autoin, Integer serverId) {
        this.autoin = autoin;
        this.serverId = serverId;
    }

    @Column(name = "autoin_fix")
    public Long getAutoin() {
        return this.autoin;
    }

    @Column(name = "servdat_fk")
    public Integer getServerId() {
        return this.serverId;
    }

    public void setAutoin(Long autoin) {
        this.autoin = autoin;
    }

    public void setServerId(Integer serverId) {
        this.serverId = serverId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((this.autoin == null) ? 0 : this.autoin.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((this.serverId == null) ? 0 : this.serverId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ID other = (ID) obj;
        if (this.autoin == null) {
            if (other.autoin != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.autoin.equals(other.autoin)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.serverId == null) {
            if (other.serverId != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.serverId.equals(other.serverId)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("ID [").append(this.autoin)
                .append("_").append(this.serverId).append("]").toString();
    }

}
```

The Article class:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTIKEL")
public class Article {

    private ID id;
    private List<Picture> pictures;

        ...

    @DocumentId
    @EmbeddedId
    @FieldBridge(impl = IDBridge.class)
    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "artikel_fk", referencedColumnName = "autoin_fix"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "servdat_fk", referencedColumnName = "servdat_fk") })
    @IndexedEmbedded
    public List<Picture> getPictures() {
            return pictures;
    }  

}
```

The Picture class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTBILDER")
public class Picture extends BasePicture {

    ...

    protected ID id;

    @EmbeddedId
    @FieldBridge(impl = IDBridge.class)
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES)
    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ...
}
```

EDIT2: I may have a clue where this comes from, please standby.

EDIT3: Nope, not the error.

EDIT4: Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTIKEL
(
  AUTOIN_FIX NUM10_0 DEFAULT 0,
  SERVDAT_FK NUM10_0 DEFAULT 0,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (AUTOIN_FIX,SERVDAT_FK)
);

CREATE TABLE ARTBILDER
(
  AUTOIN_FIX NUM10_0 DEFAULT 0,
  ARTIKEL_FK NUM10_0 DEFAULT 0,
  SERVDAT_FK NUM10_0 DEFAULT 0,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (AUTOIN_FIX,SERVDAT_FK)
);
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: The error is clear. You have a one-columned primary key in one table and a composite foreign key in another table. You can't create relation joining those two keys. Your situation is strange. Can you provide more info? Entities, database structure and stacktrace.

Comment: full stacktrace is not available, sry.

Comment: Please post the information @FlyingDumpling is asking about like the entire entities (the one with the error property, picture and the embedded id) and also information about your table setup.

Comment: better? or should I provide more information?

Comment: What is the definition of the table?

Comment: added the DDL to the question.

Comment: and the error disappeared again. maybe some old compiled files that didn't get erased when recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full [link and description](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)

```
OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "DATA_VALUE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_ID"),
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NM")
    })    
    List<DataValue> dataValueList;
```

**OR** more Descriptive

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    public ParentPk id;
    public int age;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="parentCivility", referencedColumnName = "isMale"),
        @JoinColumn(name="parentLastName", referencedColumnName = "lastName"),
        @JoinColumn(name="parentFirstName", referencedColumnName = "firstName")
    })
    public Set<Child> children; //unidirectional
    ...
}
```